# Vectors with sigma notation (R)

Tags: r, math, vector, operation

I'm now learning R and have some difficulties while computing sigma notation. I know how to do the basic stuff like this:

[image]

```
summ <- 10:100
sum(summ^3 + 4 * summ^2)
```

But I don't know how to do the same operations with the values that differ from i (include not only i (ex: x and y)) or operations with two sigma notations in a row.

[image: The A example]

At the beginning I thought that it just requires to do the same as in the simple sigma notation with only i's

```
summ <- 1:10
sum((x^summ) / (y^summ))
```

But it shows an error that it is not a numeric argument.

[image: The B example]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your example `sum((x^summ) / (y^summ))` is not replicable. What is `x` and what is `y`?

Comment: That's what I'm confused with, as there is no x and y. The task is to create the vector. Maybe, I should leave it as it is, without executing the code

Comment: ? `x<-.2; y<-.3; summ <- 1:10; sum((x^summ) / (y^summ))`

Comment: `i <- 1:20; j <- 1:10;
sum(i^2)*sum(1/(5+j^3))`

Comment: A more general approach then @jogo's: `sum(outer(1:20, 1:10, FUN = function(i, j) i^2 / (5 + j^3)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you second formula, you can define a function like below

```
f <- function(x,y,n) sum((x/y)**(1:n))
```

---

For you last formula, you can rewrite the expression as a product of two terms (you need a *math transformation* as the first step if you want to simplify the procedure), since `i` and `j` are independent

```
> sum((1:20)**2)*sum(1/(5+(1:10)**3))
[1] 886.0118
```

Otherwise, a straightforward translation from the formula could be using nested `sapply`

```
> sum(sapply(1:20,function(i) sapply(1:10, function(j) i**2/(5+j**3))))
[1] 886.0118
```

Answer (score 0):

That's, basically, the answer to the first question with undefined variables x and y:

```
x <- readline(prompt = "Enter x: ")
y <- readline(prompt = "Enter y: ")

x <- as.integer(x)
y <- as.integer(y)

i = 1:10
answer <- sum((x^i) / (y^i))

answer
```

Comment: Please provide more details and an insight, explaining the code step-by-step if possible